# iOS App Authentication to run only in Enterprise network/ Wireless

Tags: ios, security, authentication, enterprise, ios8

In Cocoa framework, do we have any class or library to define the network name. Actually I am looking to build to app which should work once you are in specific wireless/ network.

The other way to make this app authenticate is Windows Azure AD but is there any Apple specific library defined to check for the network if the yes then only app should work otherwise app gets crashed or should not work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no ios library to restrict the network access. However to achieve your requirement you can use [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009770-CH101-SW4) to get the SSID name and write custom code to not allow user to use the app.